# Get elements of model attribute in $.getjson when, elements added dynamically in controller

Tags: spring-mvc, dynamic, getjson, modelattribute

In my controller, i add multiple parameters to model attribute by some ids. for example added elements to my model in controller can be such as:

```
_104group
_105group
_106group
.
.
.
And so on
```

this elements added dynamically in controller and depends on database values. Each of these elements has a list of `MainCommodity` object. Now how can i get content of these elements in `$.getjson`?

java script is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON("<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />/mainCommodity/mainCommodity/load.html", function(object, result) {
    if (object.is_error == "1") {
        $("#addTranceButton").hide();
        var statusMessageKey = object.statusMessageKey;
        if (statusMessageKey.trim() != "") {
            $("#messages").show();
            $("#messageLabel").show() ;
            $("#messageLabel").html(statusMessageKey);
        }
    }
    else {
        for(i=0;i<commGroups.length;i++){
            alert(object);
        }
    }
});
```

I other words, i need into for loop of $.getjson success function:
 `object._104group` and `object._105group` and `object._106group` and so on .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved my problem as follows:

```
for(i=0;i<commGroups.length;i++){
     var obj = Object.values(object);
     alert(obj[i]);
}
```